# Custom query counting and grouping

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find a way to group prices in a database table by price “group”.
So my database table looks something like this:

```
+-------+------------------+
| Field | Type             |
+-------+------------------+
| id    | int(11) unsigned |
| name  | varchar(255)     |
| price | varchar(30)      |
+-------+------------------+
```

Those are the relevant fields in my database table.
What I'm trying to accomplish is to run a query that will group results by price range, so items that fall between $1 and $10 would go into group #1; $11 to $20 would go into price group #2, etc… so it should look like this:

```
+-------------+------------+
| price_group | item_count |
+-------------+------------+
| $1-$10      | 10         |
+-------------+------------+
| $11-$20     | 8          |
+-------------+------------+
| $21-$30     | 22         |
+-------------+------------+
| $31-$40     | 58         |
+-------------+------------+
| $41-$40     | 3          |
+-------------+------------+
```

I don't have any code that I've tried because I'm not really sure where to begin on this. Still searching trying to find a clue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but did you mean the prices are stored as varchars? Also, how many price_groups are there?

Comment: Yes, prices are stored as varchar at the moment.
I'll have to look through the code and see if I can change it to decimal, but I think it would be possible.
The number of price groups can be as many as I want - although I think we decided on 7, going up to $100.

Comment: I changed the field types to Decimal to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by the price (offset by 1 because of where you put your group divisions), divided by ten, cast to an integer. Consider the group $21-$30. If you subtract one, that will be $20-$29. Divide by ten (and cast to integer), anything in that group will return $2, giving you a constant for the price group.

```
SELECT CAST((price - 1) / 10 AS UNSIGNED) AS price_group, 
    SUM(item_count) as total_item_count
FROM table_name
GROUP BY price_group
```

Also note that I did `SUM(item_count)` to get the total for that group.

The `price_group` returned here will just be the tens digit. For example, for group "$21-$30", `price_group` returned will be "2".

Comment: Thanks! This worked great.
Although I'm using COUNT, not SUM. COUNT would give the total number of items, SUM would give the SUM of the items (e.g. SUM(1, 2, 3, 4) = 10. COUNT(1, 2, 3, 4) = 4).